# About Inheritance in c++

Tags: c++

If a class is inherited in public mode so public members and protected members of base class will go in public and protected section of derivied class.
My question is: if there is no protected section in derived class then what will happen?

Comment: They will be implicitly inherited anyway.

Comment: This question would be better if you had actually tested this, included the test code in the question, and asked for explanation/confirmation of the results you got from your test.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing will "happen". The class simply will not have `protected` members other than those of its base(s).

If you don't write `protected:`, that doesn't mean the class is incapable of having [inherited] `protected` members, or that it has no "protected section". Syntax and semantics are not that tightly coupled.

Answer (score 0):

With public inheritance, it does not matter if derived class has no protected section at all in its definition, or if it is empty. The protected members of base class are inherited anyway and remain protected. Same for public, even if derived class has no public section in its definition.

The `public:`/`protected:`/`private:` in calss definitions are not really "sections", they are just syntax to mark member access for the members following them until the next `public:`/`protected:`/`private:`, and you can have any number of such "sections" in any order.